# MySQL CSV export ID from second table

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I have two tables, the first table is `PRODUCTS` with fields `NAME, BUY, SELL, CATEGORY`, In the second table `CATEGORIES` with fields `NAME` and `ID`.

In the first table `CATEGORY`, is the `ID` field that references the category name

I am trying to export the product table to CSV but replace the `CATEGORY` in tables to the human readable column of NAME from the second table. I'm using MYSQL Workbench, phpmyadmin, or command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `INNER JOIN` so you can get the Category name in stead of id.

Some thing like this with out testing it:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.BUY, PRODUCTS.SELL, CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORY 
FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID;
```

This will show Category name of each product in stead of Category Id.

**Example:**

PRODUCTS table

```
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
| Id | Name  | Buy | Sell | Category |
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
|  1 | Prod1 | 100 |  200 |        1 |
|  2 | Prod2 | 100 |  200 |        2 |
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
```

CATEGORIES table

```
+----+----------+
| Id |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Hardware |
|  2 | Software |
+----+----------+
```

After inner join

```
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
| Id | Name  | Buy | Sell | Category |
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
|  1 | Prod1 | 100 |  200 | Hardware |
|  2 | Prod2 | 100 |  200 | Software |
+----+-------+-----+------+----------+
```

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575069/using-two-inner-join-tables[/link] I asked a follow up question to this here.