# Using two inner join tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join, uuid

I have come up with two queries, both use an inner join on two different tables.

### Query 1

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.CODE, PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.TAXCAT, PRODUCTS.DISPLAY,PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL, CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORY
FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID;
```

### Query 2

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.CODE, PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.TAXCAT, PRODUCTS.DISPLAY,PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL,STOCKCURRENT.UNITS AS UNIT FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN STOCKCURRENT ON STOCKCURRENT.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID;
```

Both queries run fine on their own, when I try to use both inner joins together I get errors. This is what I came up with on my own. I'm having trouble understanding the syntax to achieve this.

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.CODE, PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.TAXCAT,
PRODUCTS.DISPLAY,PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY,
PRODUCTS.PRICESELL,STOCKCURRENT.UNITS AS UNIT FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN
STOCKCURRENT ON STOCKCURRENT.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID, CATEGORIES.NAME AS
CATEGORY FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY =
CATEGORIES.ID;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted query has several syntax problems.  Assuming you just want to join together the three tables, you may try the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.CODE,
    p.REFERENCE,
    p.TAXCAT,
    p.DISPLAY,
    p.NAME,
    p.PRICEBUY,
    p.PRICESELL,
    s.UNITS AS UNIT,
    c.NAME AS CATEGORY
FROM PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN STOCKCURRENT s
    ON s.PRODUCT = p.ID
INNER JOIN CATEGORIES c
    ON p.CATEGORY = c.ID;
```

Note that I introduced table *aliases* here.  These aliases can be used elsewhere in the query to avoid having to repeat the entire table name.

By the way, I can also see taking a union of your two original queries.  But without expected output, it was not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Your proper formatting as helped me understand syntax much better.